# Can't access NodeJS server using express-generator from another computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-generator

Finally, I have tested my project and I got the problem.

I opened the NodeJS server using ExpressJS. In local, Everything is OK.

But, Another computer can not access my server.

My ip address is '172.30.6.191' and my port is '8080'.

I don't change the express-generator basic code.

Here is WWW.js file code.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('skeleton1:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

How to access this server from another computer.

Help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you're running this on an IPv4 address, more than likely it's running inside of your local network. You need to either port forward the port on your router or have the other computer on the same network and make sure to use your local IP.

Comment: @PaulBGD Umm... Excuse me. Please give me a information more details?

Comment: What more details do you need?

Comment: @PaulBGD How to do port forward. Can I control this? And How do I know  the other computer on the same network? My server computer IP address is 172.30.6.191 and the another computer IP address is 172.30.6.160.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with javascript, node.js, express, or express-generator.

To port forward is a huge topic that is different depending on your router.
To know if you're on the same network you can try pinging the other computer.

Comment: @PaulBGD Thank you. I solved the problem. Umm...it's from just firewall. I did not realize that my firewall settings changed as I moved in the office a few days ago. Thank you once more. Always have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the other computer is also on the same wifi network.

Comment: The server IP address 172.30.6.191 and another computer's IP address is 172.30.6.160. Is this not the same network? The network don't use wifi, use the LAN.